# Move semantic unintentionally superseded by copy constructor in class that encapsulates pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I made a template class `derived_object<T>` that is very similar to `std::unique_ptr`. It has the additional feature, that you can make a deep copy, although `T` is only a base class of the actual object. The technique is taken from `boost::any`. Here is the (unfortunately long) content of the file `derived_object.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>

template<class Base>
class derived_object
{
public:
    derived_object()
        : content(nullptr)
    {}

    template<typename Derived>
    derived_object(Derived* ptr)
        : content(new holder<Derived>(ptr))
    {
        static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Derived>::value, "type of pointer must have copy constructor");
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value, "type of pointer must be derived from base type");
    }

    derived_object(derived_object const& other); // left unimplemented for testing
//      : content(other.content ? other.content->clone() : nullptr)
//  {}

    derived_object& operator=(derived_object const& rhs); // left unimplemented for testing
//  {
//      derived_object<Base>(rhs).swap(*this);
//      return *this;
//  }

    derived_object(derived_object&& other) noexcept
        : content(other.content)
    {
        other.content = nullptr;
    }

    derived_object& operator=(derived_object&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        rhs.swap(*this);
        derived_object<Base>().swap(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    ~derived_object()
    {
        delete content;
    }

    Base* operator->() const
    {
        return content->operator Base*();
    }

    Base* get() const
    {
        return content->operator Base*();
    }

    derived_object& swap(derived_object& rhs) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(content, rhs.content);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    class placeholder
    {
    public:
        virtual ~placeholder() {}
        virtual operator Base*() const = 0;
        virtual placeholder* clone() const = 0;
    };

    template<typename Derived>
    class holder : public placeholder
    {
        Derived* held;
    public:
        holder(Derived* der_ptr)
            : held(der_ptr)
        { }
        placeholder* clone() const override
        {
            return new holder(new Derived(*held));
        }
        ~holder() override
        {
            delete held;
        }
        operator Base*() const override { return held; }
    };

    placeholder* content;
};
```

This works nice in general. But at a specific case, where I want to use move semantics instead of copying, my program fails. For testing purposes, I deactivated copying in derived_object by declaring but not defining the corresponding methods.

Here are the contents of `classes.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "derived_object.h"

class B1
{};
class D1 : public B1
{};


class B2
{};
class D2 : public B2
{
public:
    D2(derived_object<B1> member);
    derived_object<B1> member;
};
```

`classes.cpp`

```
#include "classes.h"

D2::D2(derived_object<B1> m)
:   member(std::move(m))
{}
```

and `main.cpp`

```
#include "classes.h"

int main()
{
    derived_object<B2> e(new D2(new D1()));
}
```

Compiling with Clang (version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4) via

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -o main.cpp.o -c main.cpp
clang++ -std=c++14 -o classes.cpp.o -c classes.cpp
clang++ main.cpp.o classes.cpp.o -o output
```

gives the linker error `` main.cpp:(.text._ZN2D2C2ERKS_[_ZN2D2C2ERKS_]+0x19): undefined reference to `derived_object<B1>::derived_object(derived_object<B1> const&)' ``.

But there should be no copying of derived_object, I always moved or used the constructor `derived_object(Derived* ptr)`.

And strange, when I declare the D2 constructor inline or make other tiny changes, the error doesn’t occur.
Why does the compiler want to copy my object although moving seems to be possible?
How could I change `derived_object.h` (apart from changing its method signatures)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
derived_object& operator=(derived_object const& rhs);
derived_object(derived_object const& other);
```

to

```
derived_object& operator=(derived_object const& rhs)=delete;
derived_object(derived_object const& rhs)=delete;
```

this will give you errors at compile-time, not link time, if they are used.

[When I do this (live example)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9355f029049e2138), I get a clear error here:

```
    static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Derived>::value, "type of pointer must have copy constructor");
```

Full error:

```
main.cpp:16:9: error: static_assert failed "type of pointer must have copy constructor"
        static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Derived>::value, "type of pointer must have copy constructor");
        ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:109:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'derived_object<B2>::derived_object<D2>' requested here
    derived_object<B2> e(new D2(new D1()));
                       ^
main.cpp:76:35: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'D2'
        return new holder(new Derived(*held));
                              ^       ~~~~~
main.cpp:71:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'derived_object<B2>::holder<D2>::clone' requested here
        holder(Derived* der_ptr)
        ^
```

which then points me here:

```
        placeholder* clone() const override
        {
            return new holder(new Derived(*held));
        }
```

You'll notice you rae *copying* `*held` here, and what more you *intend* to copy `*held`.

The class containing that `clone` is created here:

```
content(new holder<Derived>(ptr))
```

which then invokes the copy constructor of `D2`, which implicitly copies `member`, which is of type `derived_object`.

When you include the copy constructor of `derived_object` but leave it unimplemented, that implicit copy of `derived_object` within the generated copy constructor of `D2` causes your link error.  It is used in `derived_object<D2>` when it creates the `holder<D2>` type.

Virtual functions, even if never called, are implemented and compiled.

We then implement the two methods:

```
derived_object(derived_object const& other):
  content(other.content?other.content->clone():nullptr)
{}
derived_object& operator=(derived_object const& rhs) {
  auto tmp = rhs;
  return (*this)=std::move(tmp);
}
```

[and everything builds fine (live example)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0420905aeb4a497).

Note that the deep copy isn't copying based off the base type here.  We have type erased cloning of the actual derived type, not the base type.

Alternatively, to confirm there are no stupid copies done, we both leave the copy assign and ctor unimplemented, and we remove `clone`.  [This also compiles (live example)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c02bcd4ff1ca9e0b).

Comment: It is indeed the clone method although never used. I commented it out, thanks. There were other cases where the linker didn’t fail, probably because of clever optimizations. (?) No matter.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the copy constructor (with `= delete`syntax) instead of leaving it undefined should give you a more relevant hint from the compiler that should draw your attention to the line:

`return new holder(new Derived(*held));`

There is an evident copy of a named member variable.